# Ubuntu 18.04: Ethernet connected but no internet connection

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, ethernet

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an old Macbook (white plastic). In order to avoid a hang during installation I did not install third-party drivers. The install went fine after that but I have no wifi drivers installed, it seems. So I have plugged the machine directly into the router via the Ethernet port.

It refused to connect via DHCP so I entered the settings manually. It then, after some deliberation, flashed the 'could not connect' message but then actually connected. However, I seem to have no actual connection - I can't ping the router, I can't connect to the Internet, and I don't even have ifconfig installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: The installation process made a wifi network connection? That usually happens.

Comment: If you entered the settings manually, you need to go to your router settings and set the static IP in your router settings. Can you please include the hardware specs? Thanks!